# Why is laravel showing a server error

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5.1, ubuntu-14.10

I am looking to get a simple site up using laravel 5.1 I have a ubuntu 14.10 box and file zilla.
After dragging the contents of my app folder over to var/www/html/ I have changed the /etc/apache2/sites-availablemyapp.conf to read

```
<VirtualHost *:80> ServerName 104.236.27.195 ServerAlias mugendoassociationofireland.ie
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/public/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I keep getting a server error but the pointer is working. When I swap out the index.php content to 'hello' then the page will display this.
Any idea what could be missing?

Comment: What error? Possible you've got syntax errors all over the place... But who knows?

Comment: Not sure thats all that it is saying. 'The website encountered an error while retrieving' Everything is working locally on homestead and all ive done is replace a L4 app from /html/ with a L5.1 app. Im wondering if my .env file is going up.

Comment: You don't provide enough info.  Your first task is to check the error log on the server.  Look in /var/log/apache2/.  It could be something as simple as a file permission.  For example, Laravel needs write permission for 'storage' and 'bootstrap/cache'.  That might be why it works locally but not remotely.

Comment: Check your document root. Did you point it to your Laravel project ?